# How do I fix a "Unable to add data connection. The IVsDataConnectionDialog could not be initialized" error?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, server-explorer

I'm getting an error in Visual Studio 2008 anytime I try to create a data connection in the Server Explorer: "Unable to add data connection. The IVsDataConnectionDialog could not be initialized"

Also, the existing data connections are disabled and their icon is a red-slash-circle.

So far, the only advice I've found is here:
[msdn_microsoft_Forums_vbide_thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/14683181-7a23-4f01-93d5-5af3153b4cf3) Choices there include:

- Reinstall VS2008
- Reinistall .net 3.5 sp1
- rename registry for vs2008 user settings

..but I've tried each recommendation to no avail.

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sweet GLORY!!! This is fixed now.

BIG thanks to Glenn Berry on this post:
[msdn_microsoft_Vsexpressinstall](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/ae47e254-e4af-4290-a221-1abd7ad839d0)
So I went into these folders:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\{my login}\Application Data\Microsoft
C:\Documents and Settings\{my login}\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft
```

... and changed the VisualStudio folder name to `VisualStudioXXX`

When I restarted the VS2008 I was able to add new data connections in the Server Explorer.

Comment: Thanks... VS2015 here; Went into

`c:\users\{user}\appdata\roaming\microsoft\{rename visualstudio folder}
c:\users\{user}\appdata\local\microsoft\{rename visualstudio folder}`

Restarted VS and all is good.

Answer (score 4):

This fixed the same problem for me.

Try to modify the registry:

1. Open the registry
2. Rename `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0]` to `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0back]`
3. Restart Visual Studio

Credits: [msdn_microsoft_vbide_thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/14683181-7a23-4f01-93d5-5af3153b4cf3)

Comment: That's worked thanks a lot you save my a lot time.
again thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a different error like:

```
Unable to add data connection. Could not find a part of the path
'c:\Programmer\Microsoft Visual Studio
9.0\DBPro\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Data.SqlViewExtensions.xml'.
at DataViewSupport(4,3)
```

Deleting the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\DataProviders\{91510608-8809-4020-8897-FBA057E22D54}\TSDataViewExtensions
```

and restarting VS.NET,
as suggested at 
[msdn_microsoft_forums_vstsdb_thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/8981a078-0104-4ee7-ac34-404cfb7df97d), did the trick for me.