# Visual Studio 2010 and creating Local Database Connection causes error with regkey

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry

I'm trying to create a local database for my first Visual Studio project, I get this error when I try to open a Database Connection in my Server Explorer

[image]

The problem seems to be a missing \ between Visual Studio and VSTSDB in the url.

I've read up on other threads but they all have this problem in Visual Studio 2008, so for example none of the solutions given in this thread [How do I fix a "Unable to add data connection. The IVsDataConnectionDialog could not be initialized" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976542/how-do-i-fix-a-unable-to-add-data-connection-the-ivsdataconnectiondialog-could) works for me, I've tried them all.

The reg key paths given in the given url above doesn't work, I guess since I'm in Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010, and the thread is alot older.

I've localised the reg key for this url here

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/VisualStudio/10.0_Config/DataProviders/{91510608-8809-4020-8897-FBA057E22D54}/TSDataViewExtensions
```

it has the value

> E:\Program\Visual
>   StudioVSTSDB\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Schema.SEExtensions.xml

as you can see the \ is missing from the url between Visual Studio and VSTSDB, but everytime I change this and reboot, Visual Studio just changes it back to the old url when I try to create a local database and causes the crash... again.

Is there any way to permanently fix this reg key or anything else I can do?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility  http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall

and now it magically works. I have no idea what to say, except that I had it installed on E: before, now I installed it in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0

I think this made the difference for some reason. Sorry for the unclear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rechecked the D:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host in notepad and 
add the line:  127.0.0.1       localhost
corrected !